# Selecting unique names from two tables and sumiing the count against each if present in both

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table - Storage_1 and Storage_2 .

Storage_1

```
First Name     Male Count       Female Count
Ankush             70                10
Xenia              10                60
Jacky              25                70
Vivian             15                05
```

Storage_2

```
First Name      Male Count         Female Count
Rahul               50                  10
Maneek              40                  25
Jacky               30                  15
Xenia               05                  80
```

I want to see that from both the table, the names which are unique, I want to see its sum of both male count and female count. And also, the first names with their male count and female count which doesnot exist in the other table.

Heres the output I want to clear out the confusion, if any.

final Database table:

```
First Name       Male Count    Female Count
Jacky               55              85
Xenia               15              140
Ankush              70              10
Vivian              15              05
Rahul               50              10
Maneek              40              25
```

I am really struggling a long with this. Please help. It would be helpful for me if the answer is posted in terms of SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. GROUP BY its result. SUM the counts.

Comment: Hi Jarlh,
These are the tables gathered from two different databases. I have combine them and make them one. I hope that makes clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` here. then group by result for First_Name .

```
Select First_Name, sum(Male_Count) As Male_Count, sum(FeMale_Count) As FeMale_Count
     from (
        Select First_Name,Male_Count, FeMale_Count from Storage_1 
            Union All
        Select First_Name,Male_Count, FeMale_Count from Storage_2
        )T
 Group By  First_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select firstname,
       sum(male_count) as male_count,
       sum(female_count) as female_count
from ((select firstname, male_count, female_count
       from Storage_1
      ) union all
      (select firstname, male_count, female_count
       from Storage_2
      )
     ) s
group by firstname;
```

Comment: Wont male_count and female_count should be s.male_count and s.female_count in your top select clause?

Comment: @Learning . . . You can qualify the names if you like.  I'm not pendantic when there is only one table/subquery in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concat tables and pass null variables;

```
SELECT 
        COALESCE(S1.First_Name,S2.First_Name),
        ISNULL(S1.MaleCount,0)+ISNULL(S2.MaleCount,0) As MaleCount,
        ISNULL(S1.FemaleCount,0)+ISNULL(S2.FemaleCount,0) AS FemaleCount
 FROM Storage1 S1
FULL OUTER JOIN Storage2 S2 ON S1.First_Name = S2.First_Name
```

Comment: Hi Abdulkadir,
Thanks for your answers. It made my concept clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` inside of a CTE and then `GROUP BY` column [First Name]

```
;WITH CTE_All AS (
    SELECT [First Name], [Male Count], [Female Count] FROM Storage_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [First Name], [Male Count], [Female Count] FROM Storage_2
)SELECT
    [First Name]
    ,SUM([Male Count]) AS [Male Count]
    ,SUM([Female Count]) AS [Female Count]
FROM CTE_All
GROUP BY [First Name]
```